# Serialize list object to XML value exception: There was an error reflecting type "..Otrx"

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I create an object for serialize to xml: details of this object like below:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="trx")]
public class OTrx{
    [XmlElement("body")]
    public OBody Body {get;set;}
}
```

and this is clas OBody:

```
public class OBody {
        [XmlElement("list")]
            public Olist list {get;set;}
    }
```

, class Olist:

```
public class Olist {
            [XmlAttribute("h")]
                public string h {get;set;}
 [XmlAttribute("colcnt")]
                public string list {get;set;}
 [XmlAttribute("list")]
                public stringlist {get;set;}
 [XmlElement("row")]
                public List<ORow> RowList {get;set;}
        }
```

class ORow:

```
public class ORow{
            [XmlElement("col")]
                public List<OCol> ColList {get;set;}
        }
```

class OCol:

```
public class OCol{
    [XmlText]
    public string Text {get;set;}
    public Ocol(string val){
     this.Text=val;
    }
}
```

and this is the output I need:

```
<trx>
....
<body>
<list h="a,b,c,d,e" colcnt="5" rowcnt="5">
   <row>
       <col>value1</col>
       <col>value2</col>
       <col>value3</col>
       <col>value4</col>
       <col>value5</col>
  </row>
 <row>...</row>
 <row>...</row>
 <row>...</row>
 <row>...</row>
</list>
</body>
</trx>
```

I debug the code, it's show that exception happen in the List, when I comment that list, the serialization is success like :

```
<row/><row/><row/><row/><row/><row/><row/><row/>
</list></body></trx>
```

Please tell me what am I wrong ?

Comment: in terms of looking at your code - should the current `list` be `colcnt`, with the next one being `string list` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

underneath the exception about

> Cannot serialize member 'ORow.ColList' of type '...', see inner exception for more details.

it says, in the inner exception (as stated):

> OCol cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

So: add a parameterless constructor:

```
public OCol() { }
```

or just remove the explicit constructor, which is probably easier.

Actually, I don't think you need a type for `col` *at all* - this should work in `ORow`:

```
public class ORow
{
    [XmlElement("col")]
    public List<string> Values { get; set; } 
}
```

---

To be honest though, your model seems over-complicated for what you need. When unsure, perhaps the most pragmatic thing to do is to copy the **xml** you want, and use Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML As Classes and you get something that will work for the xml you want (although which can often be cleaned up significantly).

[image]

Comment: But in the InnerException it only "There was an error reflecting type '...OBody'"

Comment: @HienND there about 6 levels of inner exception in this case. Unroll all of them and write the .Message of each. I got that message from your code (ish)

Comment: Thank you for your lesson :))